# How to give size to table view to XIB

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift4, xib

I am new to iOS practicing XIB I have created an XIB for a cell

[image]

Now When I resize it from here I automatically change its behaviour in tableview I want to give this XIB with as 100% of tableview. I actually want to set Width of this XIB as tableview

[image]

Comment: The width is set automatically by the table view. You don't need to do anything.

Comment: Share your codes, It's not possible to tell what you doing wrong!

Comment: Using Auto layout and Size Classes should be enough to solve this problem

Comment: yes with is auto.... but if is drag this XIB size the size of table cell associated with this XIB automatically changes its behaviour

Comment: I haven't done any thing .... I just used it ... didn't made any change to design

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the size in the UITableViewDelegate's `heightForRowAt(_:)` method.

For purposes of building UI in interface builder, you can just drag the corner into the size you want.

Comment: I want to set width

Comment: as it is dragged the width did remain constant

Answer (score 1):

If you have your constraints setup correctly, the size you use to layout your cell in your XIB has no effect on the resulting use in a table view.

For example, with this layout:

[image]

I can stretch the frame like this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

and it will ***ALWAYS*** look like this when I run the app:

[image]

Comment: yes this is an issue with constraints .... I am very poor with it

Comment: @NoorAhmedNatali - ok, then follow the constraints I showed and that should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return tableView.frame.height
}
```

Comment: I want to change width

Comment: The cells in the tableview are supposed to be as wide as tableview. But I think you can change the cell's padding somehow, or even a better solution is to change from tableView to collectionView because collectionView cells are easy to resize.

Comment: thanks bro... I got the ans... actually I was creating a CAlayer inside my XIB... so for that very 1st time it was talking with of XIB frame ....!

Comment: @NoorAhmedNatali, I am doing the same thing, how did you fix it using the CALayer?

Comment: no it can work properly without CALayer